# How to use pivote to find out the max value from a row with three columns, that is max value out of three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have following table named as '**Table**',

[image]

Where I want result like following table where if you take first row and last three columns I want value to be 56.

[image]

I want sql server code for above table '**Table**' and result to be second table. Here MaxV-1 and MaxV-2 are dependent on '**Number**' column. **MaxV-1** is max value out of **FirstV**, **SecondV** and **ThirdV** when **Number** is equal to 1 and same logic for **MaxV-2**.

Comment: you can read this example: [basic pivot](https://hasanmahmood.com/2019/03/19/basic-pivot-sql-query/)

Comment: What version of SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is an unpivot and conditional aggreation:

```
select t.model,
       max(case when t.number = 1 then t.pro_code end) as pro_code_1,
       max(case when t.number = 2 then t.pro_code end) as pro_code_2,
       max(case when t.number = 1 then v.v end) as max_val_1,
       max(case when t.number = 2 then v.v end) as max_val_2
from t cross apply
     (select max(v.v) as v
      from (values (t.firstv), (t.secondv), (t.thirdv)) v(v)
     ) v
group by t.model;
```

Comment: Any time I come across a question that looks like it would be perfect for a PIVOT, I step back and ask myself "What Would Gordon Do?"